# How do I find the last instance of a string in a log?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I made a log file, and I want to take it and want to find the last instance that the specific user was online, the log file looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
Logging started: 2019-12-05 12:42:19.591833 

Num of members in Test Server: 12
Members: 

test12345#0720
A part of server: Test Server
Current status: idle
Current activity: None 

Logging complete
-----------------
```

Now this repeats multiple times because it adds a new log every **X** amount of time, and I want to find the last time Z user was online. (I have the name and discriminator of the user)

Comment: And `test12345#0720` is the name and discriminator of the user?

Comment: Yeah the test12345 is an example of the name and the 0720 is the descriminator. The Current status is what I want to find when last it says online

Comment: "Find that last instance". What is the exact format you need? A string? Containing what data?

Comment: I need the the date and time (string or datetime) of the last time The current status part says online

Comment: I would use regex I guess to match each logs. Another hacky way to get the work done would be to split on a common pattern occuring in the logs and get the last instance (or last but one instance, depending on how you split).

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line-by-line, and collect everything into a list up to a `Logging complete`, then check if user was present and store the candidate in an auxiliary variable, then continue with an empty list.
At the end the auxiliary variable will contain the last log block when the user was present.

Something like this:

```
user="test12345#0720"
last=None
current=[]
with open("test.log") as f:
  for line in f:
    current.append(line.strip()) # line contains the line-break character(s) too
    if line.startswith("Logging complete"): # if there may be extra info in the line
      if user in current:
        last=current
      current=[]
if last:
  print("\n".join(last))
```

(It collects the `------` lines too, getting rid of them is left to the reader)